# Error 1 The type or namespace name 'ProductServiceClient' could not be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)

Tags: c#, wcf

Just trying to create a wcf test client.
I added a service client using GardenClient.GardenServiceReference;
I have the project on http://github.com/vboyz2knight/WcfGardenService using 2010 visual studio IDE

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using GardenClient.GardenServiceReference;


namespace GardenClient
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            //Trying to create a test client
            ProductServiceClient client = new ProductServiceClient();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: update your servicereference and try

Comment: I already already service reference, same error.  The project target .net framework 4 client profile, output type console application

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You probably are missing a wcf service assembly reference.
You can add it via Solution -> Project -> Add Service Reference.

Comment: I looked into the reference file and found out I misspelled ProductServiceCLient, suppose to be GardenServiceClient